# Is there a way to change the line ending style in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, linestyle

Is there a setting for this?

Sublime Text to autocompletes braces (curly brackets) using the end-of-the line style. Convention at work is to use beginning-of-the-line (or [Allman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style)) style. Is this configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most optimal way to accomplish this, as this will not be project or language specific, is to edit your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` (or the file appropriate to your OS) and add:

```
{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n{\n\t$0\n}"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\)", "match_all": true }
  ]
}
```

This will result in the following behavior when <kbd>{</kbd> is pressed, *only* when the preceding character is `)`:

[image]
[image]